# Unable to access Azure SQL copied DB using same credentials

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm automating the setup of an Azure SQL DB, copied from an existing DB. This is done programatically from a .NET application using the following query:

```
CREATE DATABASE [my_db_copy] AS COPY OF [my_db];
```

The DB is copied on the same server as the source DB.

Once created I use the same connection string (but with the `Initial Catalog` now changed to `my_db_copy`) to access the DB. At this point I encounter...

> SqlException: Cannot open database "my_db_copy" requested by the login. The login failed.

I can see the copied DB in SSMS but if I try to run any query on it (while logged-in as the same user which created the DB)...

[image]

As I've read on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy#resolve-logins)...

> All users in the new database retain the permissions that they had in the source database. The user who initiated the database copy becomes the database owner of the new database. After the copying succeeds and before other users are remapped, only the database owner can log in to the new database.

My interpretation of that statement is that I should be able to *access* the copied DB using the same login with which I *created* the copied DB. But I can't.

What else do I need to do?

**UPDATE**
As @mauridb says in his answer, the DB is not ready, despite the SQL query returning (and the docs say "The T-SQL statement continues running until the database copy operation is complete." which implies that once the statement returns the DB is ready). However, querying `sys.dm_operation_status` shows

> operation = CREATE DATABASE COPY

and

> status = COMPLETE

but the DB is still not accessible.

In the end I had to run a a simply query in a loop to pool for the DB being accessible. I found that it takes approximately 1 minute after the query returns before a connection may be opened on the DB.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to access the database while it is not available yet. You can check the status by querying [`sys.dm_operation_status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-operation-status-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) in the `master` database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell#monitor-the-progress-of-the-copying-operation

Comment: You're right, the DB is not available yet. This is despite the docs suggesting that it should be. See my updated OP.